# Error on unserialize() when decrypting laravel session cookie

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, encryption, cookies, laravel-5.7

I'm trying to decrypt a Laravel 5.7 session cookie (passed in the request), to authenticate users in a websocket.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt;
...
$cookie = $request->get('session_cookie')
$sessionId = Crypt::decrypt($cookie);
```

However I always get:

```
unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 40 bytes
```

I already tried clearing the cookies on the client, restarted the server and reset the app key with

```
php artisan key:generate
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Laravel made a change to the way it handles cookies from V5.6.30 to improve security.  It may be that you are trying to decrypt something that isn't serialized or vice versa.  You can try a couple of things:

```
$sessionId = Crypt::decrypt($cookie, false);
```

Or, within the middleware `app\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies.php`, you can flip it to test:

add: `protected static $serialize = true;`